# Linear Algebra, Vector Spaces (Subspace Theorem)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Question:

"Let F(−∞, ∞) represents the set of all real valued function defined on (−∞, ∞).
Using the subspace theorem, show that the set of all differentiable functions on  (−∞, ∞) that satisfy *f*'(x)+2 *f*(x)=0 is a subspace of F(−∞, ∞)"

Where I'm at:

I have proven that this set is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Addition: 
Let *f* and *g* be differentiable functions where *f*'(x)+2 *f*(x)=0 and *g*'(x)+2 *g*(x)=0
(*f*+*g*)'+2(*f*+*g*) = (*f*'+2 *f*)+(*g*'+2 *g*) = 0

Multiplication= 
Let *k* be any scalar,
(*kf*)'+2(*kf*) = *kf*'+2 *kf* = *k*(*f*'+2 *f*)=*k*(0) = 0

Is there any need to prove that this set is nonempty? If yes, can you kindly help with this, please.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Let $W$ the set of all functions $f$ in $F(-\infty,\infty)$ that satisfy $$f'(x)+2f(x)=0$$
This set is not empty since the function $f:(-\infty,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=e^{-2x}$ belongs to $W$.

Comment: You could also show that it contains the zero function.

Comment: Hi,thank you for your responses. @ÁngelMarioGallegos, just want to make sure - W is the subspace of   f(−∞,∞), right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, the set of all functions that are differentiable on $(-\infty, \infty)$ are a subset of the set of all real-valued functions in $(-\infty, \infty)$.

You "do" need to show it is non-empty, mainly by showing the zero vector is in the subspace, which is simple.

You can show that the set is not empty and that it contains the zero vector (that is the zero-mapped function). In this case, the zero vector is just the zero function, and it is trivially in this set. From above you have also shown is closure in addition and subtraction, you do not need to show anymore.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.
so you mean to show that f'(0)+2f(0) ∈ S?

In addition, would it be ok if I sub f'(x) to be f' and 2f(x) to be 2f just like what I wrote in the question?

Comment: Yes, that would suffice